# C++ unsigned char *{varName}; -> C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, byte, unsigned-char

I have DLL written in C++. I need to use it in my C# code
I am trying to make such object of C++ in C#:

```
typedef struct {
int width;
int height;
int stride;
unsigned char *pixels;} FIS_Image;
```

Does `unsigned char *pixels;` in C++ will be `byte pixels;` in C#?

Comment: try this `public class XYZ
{
public int width;
public int height;
public int stride;
public byte pixels;
}'

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned char is from 0-255, it is an unsigned byte. Don't get confused by the word `char` here. So the C# equivalent is `byte`.

Comment: I found that '*' sign means pointer in C++. Maybe that is why I am not getting  the result.

Comment: @KomiljonAliyev You need to properly learn C++ *(well C in that case)* before wanting to do interop.